# "erlernt" vs "gelernt"

Tags: difference, german-to-english, past-participle, past

I'm having a hard time telling the difference in meaning between ***erlernt*** and ***gelernt***. When I look them up in a GER-ENG dictionary, both translate to "learned". However, it seems that *erlernt* is used for the present perfect? Is *gelernt* used only for the past perfect then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/erlernen-versus-lernen/26391

Answer (score 14):

In this case the difference is not related to tenses. *Erlernen* and *lernen* are two different verbs.

More often than not *er* can be identified with a (non-separable) prefix that implies to do the things until the goal is reached ("Vorsilbe, die eine zielgerichtete Handlung ausdrückt"). Hence, *erlernen* is to learn something until you master it, while *lernen* might only be the process.

> [**erlernen**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erlernen): sich lernend mit einer Sache beschäftigen, bis man sie beherrscht

You might wish to know something more [here](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/er-). E.g. *erschießen* means to shoot somebody dead, till the goal is accomplished (i.e. dies); while *schießen* can be only to shoot. Or *ertrinken* (drown); one "drinks" water till one dies.

My favorite is *erinnern* (to see into yourself until you find the thing you are looking for, till you remember).

Comment: Now I have this picture in my mind of someone drinking and drinking and drinking. But it's a good explanation though. +1 :)

Comment: Wow! That is a really helpful explanation and I think I understand the difference now. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question so thoroughly. And like Em1, I get the visual image of erschießen, like a scene from some gratuitous action movie, haha.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear explanation. I am reading Kafkas “Brief an den Vater” where I came upon the sentence: “… man kann sagen daß ich wenig gelernt und nichts erlernt habe.“ I think I now understand what he means.

Answer (score 5):

*Erlernen* is an interesting derivation of *lernen* - or better a "specification". While *lernen* can be used to express *learning pretty much anything*, *erlernen* is almost exclusively used with regard to *learning a skill or job* and thus also implies a certain level of complexity of the subject that has been learned. (The term x-handwerk is also used very often in this context, implying that *erlernen* has a focus on manual/practical skill - though not exclusively)

> Er ging nach Hamburg, wo er das Tischlerhandwerk erlernte.
>
> He went to Hamburg where he learned/trained to become a carpenter.

Please note that it would sound weird to use *erlernen* with the actual job title/description in German, *erlernen* refers to the skill (carpentry, craftsmanship, etc.).

*Erlernen* in everyday spoken (and even written) German does sound quite anachronistic. As in the example I gave earlier, you are likely to find it in rather formal texts such as biographies or encyclopedia entries. Germans usually use *lernen* nowadays.

An interesting grammatical construction is how people tell you about the job/trade they learned nowadays. In the example I gave earlier *erlernen* was used in conjunction with the job/trade.

> Er hat das Fleischerhandwerk erlernt
>
> He learned to become a butcher

Today people would use *lernen* in conjuction with the job title, not the actual skill. Like this:

> Ich habe Fleischer gelernt
>
> I learned to be a butcher

Comment: Ahh, ok~ I appreciate your very clear explanation, especially with the examples. Thank you for informing me of the distinction between the trade and the title, and for telling me that it's not as commonly used. One of the more difficult things is to know which words are considered dated, at risk of sounding unnatural. I'm grateful for the help!

Comment: I would not necessarily consider "erlernen" dated, but rather a bit formal and probably not used so much in spoken language. One thing to add might be that "erlernen" generally implies to learn something through practice, rather than studying.

Answer (score 1):

"Er-" is a verb modifier that *modifies* the underlying verb. Even though it is not a preposition, it performs a similar role to prepositions such as an- auf- aus- that modify verbs when they are prefixes before a verb.

"Er-" is a modifier that means to "complete" or "fulfill." So lernen is the underlying verb for "to learn," and "erlernen" modifies it to "completely learn" (or "master.")

In any event, erlernen is not a "tense" of lernen; instead, erlernt is the past tense of erlernen. Gelernt is the past tense of lernen.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of "erlernen" is, that you mastered it yourself. A dog for example can't er-learn a trick, but he can learn it. You didn't er-learn your mothers tongue, because you didn't master it, it came naturally by listening to your parents for years. You plain learnt your language.

The same goes for all words with er-prefix:

erlernt
erarbeitet
erjagt
erklettert
erschlichen
erbettelt
erfochten
erschmeichelt
erlogen
erträumt

It means that whatever you are talking about, didn't came naturally but you were the driving power behind it.

Comment: erblühen, erbosen, erfahren, erfolgen, erfreuen, erfrieren, ergrauen, erhalten, ...