# „Erlernen“ versus „Lernen“?

Tags: difference, word-choice

Ich habe das Folgende in der Zeitung gelesen:

> Da muss die Sprache erlernt werden

Warum haben sie hier *erlernt* verwendet? Was zusätzlich zu einfach *lernen* fügt es hinzu?

Wenn man „Da muss die Sprache *ge*lernt werden“ geschrieben hätte, was wäre (wenn überhaupt) der Unterschied?

Comment: Hast du den Unterschied in einem Wörterbuch nachgeschlagen? Übrigens existiert eine verwandte Frage auf Englisch: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/22367

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*erlernen* impliziert eine Grenze, die überschritten wird - ein so gennantes *telisches* Verb. *lernen* bezeichnet einen möglicherweise andauernden Prozess.

> Er [lernt/???erlernt] schon seit drei Jahren die Sprache.

Wenn jemand *Deutsch* er*lernt* hat, heißt das, diese Person kann nun Deutsch. Im Gegensatz dazu kann man *ein bisschen Deutsch lernen* oder *drei Jahre lang Deutsch lernen, ohne dass dabei viel herum kommt*.

In vielen Fällen drückt das *er-* - Präfix eine direkte, starke Erfasstheit des Objekts aus;

> Er *er*schießt ihn.

Answer (score -3):

Erlernen tust du Dinge aus dir heraus. Hunde hingegen erlernen keine Tricks sondern sie lernen sie "nur".